# Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Tags: swift, kotlin, exception

Kotlinにある `mapNotNull` を実装しようとして（Swiftなので名前は`mapNotNil`の方が適切か？）

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

というエラーが出ました。

```
extension Array {
    func mapNotNull<ElementOfResult>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> ElementOfResult) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult] {
        return self.compactMap {
            $0
        }.map {
            transform($0) // ここでエラー
        }
    }
}
```

メソッド定義を

```
func mapNotNull<ElementOfResult>(_ transform: (Element) -> ElementOfResult) -> [ElementOfResult]
```

と変えた場合、エラーは消えるのですが、これだと `mapNotNull` に渡したクロージャが例外を起こすコードを書いた場合コンパイルエラー(`to non-throwing function type`のようなコンパイルエラー)となるため、本来の map や compactMap と違う挙動となるため、よくないと考えています（本来のmap や comapctMap に近づけたいです）

うまく `rethrows` させるにはどう書けばよいのでしょうか？

**追記：**
そもそも`Element`が配列オブジェクトができたタイミングで型が決まるので、`mapNotNull` は実現できないきもしてきました...

**さらに追記**
[OptionalType もしくは OptionalProtocol はどういったテクニックなのでしょうか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/56882/optionaltype-%e3%82%82%e3%81%97%e3%81%8f%e3%81%af-optionalprotocol-%e3%81%af%e3%81%a9%e3%81%86%e3%81%84%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%83%86%e3%82%af%e3%83%8b%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%81%aa%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b)

に別の質問を足しました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーを取るだけなら

```swift
extension Array {
    func mapNotNull<ElementOfResult>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> ElementOfResult) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult] {
        return try self.compactMap { // tryを付ける
            $0
        }.map {
            try transform($0) // tryをつける
        }
    }
}
```

としてください。

あなたの欲しいメソッドはおそらくはこうです。

```swift
extension Array {
    func mapNotNull<T, ElementOfResult>(_ transform: (T) throws -> ElementOfResult) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult] 
        where Element == Optional<T> {
            return try compactMap { try $0.map(transform) }
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。よいですね！（upvoteしました）　とはいえ、下記のように（こんな書き方を普通しないと思いますが）すると、`let a = [1, 2, "3", nil].mapNotNull {
            String($0)
        }
`

$0 が、　`Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` となってしまいます。

これがなぜか `OptionalType` を使った場合 `$0` は `Any型`であるとSwiftは認識するようです。

Comment: Array<Any>型を対象とする場合は上の方法にする必要があります。　2か所に try が必要です。

Comment: さすがにAnyの件はイレギュラーな気もしてきましたので、「承認」もいたしました

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44614084/1979953

を参考に よくわかっていないですが... 下記でできました。

```
protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    var optional: Wrapped? { get }
}

extension Optional: OptionalType {
    var optional: Wrapped? { return self }
}

extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: OptionalType {
    func removeNils() -> [Iterator.Element.Wrapped] {
        return self.compactMap { $0.optional }
    }

    func mapNotNil<R>(_ transform: (Iterator.Element.Wrapped) throws -> R) rethrows -> [R] {
        var temp: [R] = []

        for e in self {
            if let ee = e as? Iterator.Element.Wrapped {
                let t = try transform(ee)
                temp.append(t)
            }
        }

        return temp
    }
}
```