# OptionalType もしくは OptionalProtocol はどういったテクニックなのでしょうか？

Tags: swift, optional, ジェネリクス

## はじめに

[Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/56873/call-can-throw-but-it-is-not-marked-with-try-and-the-error-is-not-handled)
の質問に対して、自分自身で下記の回答をしました。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/56880/9008

## オープンソース

自分自身で回答しておきながら、よくわからない部分があるのですが、
オープンソースを見てみるとよくあるテクニック（イディオム）のように思えてきました。

### SwiftyUserDefaults（引用）

https://github.com/radex/SwiftyUserDefaults/blob/abcfe895e3119b051918fa19b8d8e009cdc44cce/Sources/OptionalType.swift

```
public protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    var wrapped: Wrapped? { get }
}

extension Optional: OptionalType {

    public var wrapped: Wrapped? {
        return self
    }
}
```

### Realm（引用）

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/930eb761c418cdd9babf2e599fb79ff22e371ffb/RealmSwift/RealmCollection.swift

```
/// :nodoc:
public protocol OptionalProtocol {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    /// :nodoc:
    // swiftlint:disable:next identifier_name
    func _rlmInferWrappedType() -> Wrapped
}

extension Optional: OptionalProtocol {
    /// :nodoc:
    // swiftlint:disable:next identifier_name
    public func _rlmInferWrappedType() -> Wrapped { return self! }
}
```

## 質問

この `OptionalType` や `OptionalProtocol` はどういったテクニックなのでしょうか？

特に
`associatedtype Wrapped`
と
Swift自体の
`public enum Optional<Wrapped> : ExpressibleByNilLiteral`
の`<Wrapped>` の関係性について教えて下さい。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***この `OptionalType` や `OptionalProtocol` はどういったテクニックなのでしょうか？***

Swiftのジェネリックに対する制限を回避するために **`Optional`型だけが適合するプロトコル**として宣言されています。

(`Optional`以外で`OptionalType` や `OptionalProtocol`に適合する型を定義することもできますが、例として挙げられた両者ともそんなことは少しも考慮していません。)

別質問の方で話題にされたようなメソッド、要素型が`Optional`の時にだけ働くような拡張メソッドを定義したい場合、現在のSwiftでは、それを自然に表現することが出来ません。

```
extension Array where Element == Optional {
    //...
}
```

`Optional`のようなジェネリック型を使用する場合、型パラメータを明示しないとエラーになります。

```
extension Array where Element == Optional<T> {
    //...
}
```

しかし、上のように書くと、未定義型`T`を使用していると言って怒られます。

```
extension<T> Array where Element == Optional<T> {
    //...
}
```

しかし、Swiftでは、extensionに新たなジェネリックパラメータを導入することは出来ず、上のような書き方はまともに構文解析さえしてくれず、意味不明のエラーになります。

そこで`Element`が`Optional`型であると言う制約を表現するために、`OptionalType`なんてプロトコルを導入し、`Optional`型だけをそのプロトコルに適合させておきます。

つまり、
「ある型が`OptionalType`に適合している」⇔「その型は`Optional`型である」
と言う状態にしてしまうわけです。

その状態では、

```
extension Array where Element: OptionalType {
    //...
}
```

なんて宣言してやれば、`Element`が`Optional`型の時にだけ有効なextensionが宣言できると言うわけです。

特に昔のSwiftでは、ジェネリック型に`==`での制約をつけることができなかったこともあり、よく使われたテクニックです。

---

現在では`==`を使った制約も使えますし、メソッド単位であればextension中で新たなジェネリックパラメータを導入することも出来るので、masakih さんの回答にあるようなコードの書き方の方が自然でしょう。

```
extension Sequence {
    func removeNils<T>() -> [T]
        where Element == Optional<T>
    {
        return self.compactMap { $0 }
    }

    func mapNotNil<R, T>(_ transform: (T) throws -> R) rethrows -> [R]
        where Element == Optional<T>
    {
        return try self.compactMap{try $0.map{try transform($0)}}
    }
}
```

すべてのメソッドに`where Element == Optional<T>`なんて制約を書くより、`Optional`型であることを示すためだけのプロトコルを定義する方がまし…なんて思う人もいるかもしれませんが。

---

***`associatedtype Wrapped`

と

Swift自体の

`public enum Optional<Wrapped> : ExpressibleByNilLiteral`

の`<Wrapped>` の関係性について***

`OptionalType.Wrapped`は、プロトコル`OptionalType`の関連型(associatedtype)、`Optional.Wrapped`はジェネリック型`Optional`の型パラメータであるわけですが、`Optional`型をプロトコル`OptionalType`に適合させることにより、両者は同じ型であるものと扱われるようになります。

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype MyAssocType

    var assocValue: MyAssocType? {get}
}
extension MyProtocol {
    func showMyAssocType() {
        print(MyAssocType.self)
    }
}

class MyClass<T> {
    var assocValue: T? = nil

    func showT() {
        print(T.self)
    }
}
extension MyClass: MyProtocol {}
let myObj = MyClass<Int>()
myObj.showT() //->Int
myObj.showMyAssocType() //->Int
```

---

**追記** コメントでいただいた内容について。

少し説明を端折りすぎてしまったようですね。

***`associatedtype` の名前はなんでもよいと思う***

その通りです。「`associatedtype` の名前」に大きな意味はありません。

```
protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype Hoge
}
extension Optional: OptionalType {
}
```

***で、　`Type 'Optional<Wrapped>' does not conform to protocol 'OptionalType'` というエラーになります。***

これまたその通りですね。ただし、このエラーは「`associatedtype` の名前」が異なっているから発生しているのではなく、「`Hoge`がどのような型になるか決定できない」ために、起こっているものです。

例えば、次のように書いてやると、エラーは出なくなります。

```
protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype Hoge

    var optional: Hoge? { get }
}
extension Optional: OptionalType {
    var optional: Wrapped? {
        return self
    }
}
```

この場合、Swiftはプロトコル`OptionalType`の実装には`var optional: Hoge?`というプロパティ(最低getterだけでOK)が必要だということを知っている状態で、`Optional`型を見るわけですが、すぐに`var optional: Wrapped? {...}`と言うプロパティが宣言されているのが見つかります。

`var optional: Hoge?`
               ↑↓
`var optional: Wrapped?`

この結果、Swiftの型推論が働いて、`OptionalType.Hoge`は`Optional.Wrapped`と同じ型である、と言うことになるわけです。

このように、「**Swiftが型推論できるような実装を含めてやることで、異なる型名でも両者が同じものを表すとSwiftにわからせることが出来ます**。」

説明がほとんど無かった点については大変失礼しましたが、先の例でも`MyProtocol.MyAssocType`と`MyClass.T`の「名前」は全く違っているのに、なぜ同じ型であるものと扱われるのか、はお分りいただけましたでしょうか。

まだまだ言葉足らずかもしれませんが、わかりにくいところがあれば、またコメントしていただけると助かります。

Comment: > 両者は同じ型であるものと扱われるようになります。

これであれば、`associatedtype` の名前はなんでもよいと思うのですが、

`protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype Hoge
}`


`extension Optional: OptionalType {}`

で、　`Type 'Optional<Wrapped>' does not conform to protocol 'OptionalType'` というエラーになります。

`Wrapped` というように `associatedtype` の名前を `Optional.Wrapped` と同名としないといけない理由はなぜでしょうか？

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。たしかに `var optional: Hoge? { get }`  を足すことで、型推論可能となるのは、納得がいったのですが、`Hoge`にしたときは、`var optional: Hoge? { get }` という情報を足す必要があるにもかかわらず、 `public protocol OptionalProtocol {
    associatedtype Wrapped
}`

`extension Optional: OptionalProtocol {
}`

と `Wrapped` と同名とした場合はコンパイルエラーが起こりません。

同名の場合は、一体何をもとにして、型推論しているのでしょうか？

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi さん、すでにその点に気付かれておられたのですね。「大きな意味はありません」と言うのは、小さな意味ならあると言うわけです。エラーの有無でわかるようにSwiftではprotocolの`associatedtype`が決定出来なければエラーになるわけですが、それを決定するのは「実装からの型推論」だけではなく、「同じ名前のジェネリックパラメータまたは`typealias`が存在する場合」にも同じ型であると決定されます。「同じ名前である必要はない」けれども「同じ名前であればうまくやってくれる場合もある」と言ったところでしょうか。ジェネリックでなしに`typealias`を使っても「同じ名前」がどう働くかわかるかと思います。

Comment: いつもありがとうございます！　やはり細かいルールがあるんですね。　はじめは、私の中でうまく理解できていなかったのですが、色々試している中で、シンプルに同名のみのコードを試しに書いたときコンパイルが通ったので、コメントという形でさらに質問してしまいました。